# Exception throw in program- not sure how to debug

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, mutex

I get an exception in the boost library file shared_ptr.hpp:

```
// Move support

#if !defined( BOOST_NO_CXX11_RVALUE_REFERENCES )

    shared_ptr( shared_ptr && r ) BOOST_NOEXCEPT : px( r.px ), pn()
    {                                       //Exception highlighted on this row
        pn.swap( r.pn );
        r.px = 0;
    }

    template<class Y>
#if !defined( BOOST_SP_NO_SP_CONVERTIBLE )

    shared_ptr( shared_ptr<Y> && r, typename boost::detail::sp_enable_if_convertible<Y,T>::type = boost::detail::sp_empty() )
```

I believe this is something to do with multiple threads reading/writing to the same object shared across them. I have (until now) not implemented any locks. In the below snippet you will see I have (unsuccessfully) used a mutex- to no avail.

I have a program (cannot put all the code here- too much) which reads data from several files (a thread per each file) and processes the data in the function below. In other words, each of the threads runs a copy of the below code:

(`idict` is shared across threads and is a `std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<I>> object)`

```
void A::y(std::vector<char> rm, std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<I> > idict){

    std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Order> > SubTickets = d->getTickets(rm);

    for(boost::shared_ptr<Order> latest_ticket : SubTickets){

        //Just a getter method on latest_ticker
        std::string sid = latest_ticket->getSID();

        //Tried using mutexes but I still get the exception???
        mtx.lock();

        if(idict.count(sid) == 1){

            //Grabs an I object from a dictionary. This dictionary is shared across threads
            boost::shared_ptr<I> oi = idict[sid];

            //Just a getter method on oi
            boost::shared_ptr<OB> iob = oi->getOB();

            //Just a getter method on oi
            boost::shared_ptr<E> ie = oi->getE();

            //latest_ticket and iob are not shared across the threads
            boost::shared_ptr<OBM> mod = ie->getOM(latest_ticket, iob);

            //cs is an object which is shared amonst threads
            cs->do(mod);
            cs->check(oi);
        }
        mtx.unlock();
    }
}
```

I appreciate the help which can be given is limited due to you not knowing whats happening between the two mutexes- but based on the above is it absolutely certain that my concurrency issue cannot be happening inside the mutexes?

EDIT:

Moved the lock() and unlock() to pretty much surrounded the whole function and I got an exception in the file sp_counted_base_w32.hpp:

```
void release() // nothrow
{
    if( BOOST_INTERLOCKED_DECREMENT( &use_count_ ) == 0 )
    {
        dispose();
        weak_release();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exception? Did you try with a debugger (e.g. catchpoint on throw)? Where else are cs and idict accessed (from other threads), and is that code protected by the same mutex?

Comment: Im using visual studio and the exceptions never seem to get caught. I go to Debug -> Exceptions and it does have the user unhandled tickbox checked for C++